# Understanding path command line

Tags: bash

Can someone explain to me what the backward slash in the second export do? Why don't we have that backward slash in the first export?

```
export PATH=/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-9.0/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-9.0/lib\
                     ${DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
```

Comment: Backslashes are line "extenders," in this case I believe.  Essentially telling the system that the export command is a concatenation of both lines 2 and 3 into one command.

Comment: this is a question about linux and has nothing specific to do with CUDA or deep-learning

Comment: @gravity: Thanks, I figured it out.

Comment: @Robert Crovella: I do now. Thanks.